# How to compile and run `main;` in C

Tags: c, compilation, program-entry-point

```c
main;
```

This is the smallest program that can be compiled in C.
Compilation warnings (`gcc`):

```
test.c:1:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘main’ [-Wimplicit-int]
test.c:1:1: warning: ‘main’ is usually a function [-Wmain]
```

I'd like to understand what it means, syntactically speaking, namely:

- why the semicolon when declaring a function ?
- why are the missing parenthesis and curly brackets legal ?

I know that the default return type of a function is `int` when omitted. I also heard of the `_start` function which is called before `main`. This would mean that it is calling a function that hasn't been defined(?).

Why exactly does the executable segfaults when run ?

Comment: Warning is very clear to understand , and there are some rules we need to follow . May be any pandits can explain why part.

Comment: Where is your [mcve]? There is nothing in your question that can be compiled and run.

Comment: BTW: the warning `type defaults to ‘int’ ....`, or any warning containing the word `implicit` should always be considered as errors.

Comment: This question is way under-rated. The fact that a C "program" consisting of just `main;` is accepted by [all](https://godbolt.org/z/8G46xa) [the](https://godbolt.org/z/xaW6b7) [major](https://godbolt.org/z/zxf475) [compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/1TMe1T) is just mind-boggling, as is the fact that you can write `myvar;` at top-level and that it defaults to `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't specify a type for `main`, the compiler is defaulting to a type of `int`.  Not a function returning an `int`, but an `int`.  This is legal from a syntactic standpoint, as you could have also had `myvar;` in your code which would also be declared as `int`.

But because `main` is special, that's why you get the second warning. It is letting you know that how you defined `main` differs from what how it is typically defined.

So when you compile this program an attempt to run it, it is expecting `main` to be the start of a function when it is actually just an `int` variable.  This is what causes the segfault.